Update of kernel on Ubuntu never succeeds
A couple of our servers do not upgrade the kernel when prompted. The following message prompt occurs:
Kernel Upgrade
Kernel Upgrade Restart
After closing and restarting the services, nothing has been updated because the next time I run the command:
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
It goes through the same process, i.e. the prompt occurs again. This happens even if I have restarted the server.
Could you point me in the right direction to fix this?

To be clear, are you saying you rebooted the whole computer? Just restarting all of the services in your second screenshot isn't enough.

Yeah .... it does not update after restarting the services ... so I tried a reboot.

You don't try to reboot, you need to do a reboot after kernel update. Only exemption is live kernel upgrade.

I contacted my server provider, and the documentation they provided for me to upgrade the Kernal on Ubuntu worked. I ran the following command, and the Kernal updated:
sudo apt update && sudo apt install linux-generic

